# Sorting Objects based on properties

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort the Points based on the X and Y properties of the point object.A small example below to explain my process:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{},{},{}]'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)


#point instances
p1,p2,p3 = Point(7,85,5), Point(56,16,20), Point(24,3,30)

point_list = [p1,p2,p3]

def get_X(point):
    return point.x

def get_Y(point):
    return point.y

sorted_points = sorted(point_list, key = get_X)
# print(sorted_points) // [[7,85,5], [24,3,30], [56,16,20]]

sorted_points = sorted(sorted(point_list, key = get_X), key = get_Y)
# print(sorted_points) // [[24,3,30], [56,16,20], [7,85,5]]
```

But I need an output like this sorting X first keep them in same order and then sort Y

```
[[7,3,5], [24,16,30], [56,85,20]]
```

I think I am trying to exchange the properties of each instances by achieving the above, But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: your order is off: You want to sort first by Y, then by X: `sorted(sorted(point_list, key = get_Y), key = get_X)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples will naturally sort in the way you want. You can simplify things by adding a `__lt__()` function to your class. `Sorted` will use this function to compare. Then you can depend on the natural sorting order of tuples easily with something like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{},{},{}]'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.x, self.y, self.z))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.x, self.y, self.z) < (other.x, other.y, other.z)



#point instances
point_list = [Point(7,85,5), Point(56,16,20), Point(24,3,30), Point(7, 20, 0), Point(56,16,15)]

sorted(point_list)
# --> [[7,20,0], [7,85,5], [24,3,30], [56,16,15], [56,16,20]]
```

**EDIT: Create new points**

To create new points by combining the sorted elements of each point individually you can unzip your points, sort them and then zip them again. The nicest way to do this is to add an `__iter__()` function to your class to make it iterable so it can support `zip`. I've done this in the code above. This will allow you to do this:

```
point_list = [Point(7,85,5), Point(56,16,20), Point(24,3,30), Point(7, 20, 0), Point(56,16,15)]
newTuples = list(zip(*[sorted(l) for l in zip(*point_list)]))
sortedPoints = [Point(*p) for p in newTuples ]

#sortedPoint => [[7,3,0], [7,16,5], [24,16,15], [56,20,20], [56,85,30]]
```

This also sorts the z values, but it's easy enough to change that if you need it for some reason.

Comment: Sorry for not making my intention clear. But I am trying to achieve something like this from your example  `[[7,3,0], [7,16,5], [24,16,30], [56,20,15], [56,85,20]]` sort the X first keep it intact and then change the Y alone

Comment: Oh sorry, that's quite unusual - you're not actually sorting the points. After the sort you end up with a totally different set of points. In this case doing this as a class method doesn't makes sense. In fact using a point class doesn't really make sense unless you create  new points during  the sort.

Comment: Ah I see, will try to create a new point while sorting it. Many thanks for illustrating the usage of `__lt__` function.

Comment: thanks a million for your explanation and solution, as a non programmer it would have taken a day for me to come up with a solution and a messy one.

Answer (score 1):

By placing the key elements in tuples in the order you want them sorted (primary value first, secondary value second), the ordering method of tuples will automatically perform in the way you are hoping to achieve.
All you need to change is that your value for `key` should be set to `key=get_XY`, where `get_XY` returns a tuple of x and y coordinates:

```
def get_XY(point):
    return point.x, point.y
```

Comment: I tried this before it gives an error `sorted_points = sorted(point_list, key = (get_X, get_Y))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`